# Why PyQt 5 doesn't working in Google Colab?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, google-colaboratory

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
```

when i run the code google colab gives Your session crashed for unknown reason error. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Google Colab runs in a headless environment, so there won't be any display for Qt to use. Why do you want to use Qt anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look at this image of  logs and u will see that Google Colab can't support the GUI app using qt

[image]